# “Method must have a return type” and "a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression" errors

Tags: c#

I'm a new learner on C# and I've been having difficulty on classes. Specifically when trying to use an object. I've been trying to make a sorta calculator and was stopped short by an error. I've trying to figure it out on my own but I seem to get more confused after trying to fix it.

I'm trying to make an application where the user inputs two numbers and it uses a class object to calculate them and bring it back to the main method. Apologies if this is asked often. And thank you in advance.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
        int num1; 
       //ask user for number
        num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a second number");
        int num2;


        //ask user for number
        num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //initialize class object
        Addition addi = new Addition();

        Console.WriteLine("The answer of both {0} and {1} is {2}", num1, num2, addi);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This is the class that will do the addition and pass it to the main method.

```
class Addition
{
   public static void Add(int x, int y)
    {
        x;
        y;
        int ans;
        ans = x + y;
        //get an error "Since 'Addition.add' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression "
        return ans;
    }


}
```

Comment: Your `Add` method is declared to return `void` (which really means it doesn't return anything). You need to change that to `int` if you want to call `return ans;`

Comment: [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/index) should be useful. When you get a syntax error, the official documentation (specially the new sites) are quite great

Comment: Also, the standalone statements `x;` and `y;` don't do anything and you can remove them (you should be getting a compile error on those). Your method can basically be reduced to one line: `return x + y;`

Comment: Thank you, Rufus. The error went away and it runs. But sadly, it seems like it didn't calculate and instead outputs "The answer of both 5 + 5 is PracticeMethod.Addition". It seems like I did something wrong in the main method.

Comment: In your first code statement, you are never calling the `Add` method. You can replace this line: `Addition addi = new Addition();` with something like: `int addi = Addition.Add(num1, num2);`

Comment: While we can help you fix all the problems with this code, that won't help you in the long run. I can see at least a dozen things I would change here for example. You **really** need to run through some C# tutorials and learn this stuff yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways the class could work... static or instanced.

### Instanced

If you want the main method to work this way....

```
Addition addi = new Addition();
Console.WriteLine("The answer of both {0} and {1} is {2}", num1, num2, addi);
```

then your Addition class should be more like this:

```
class Addition
(
    private readonly int result;

    public Addition(int num1, int num2)
    {
        result = num1 + num2;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then it will work with a small change:

```
Addition addi = new Addition(num1, num2);  //Have to pass the values in
Console.WriteLine("The answer of both {0} and {1} is {2}", num1, num2, addi);
```

### Static

A static method requires no instance, so you have to change this:

```
Addition addi = new Addition();  
Console.WriteLine("The answer of both {0} and {1} is {2}", num1, num2, addi);
```

To this:

```
var addi = Addition.Add(num1, num2);
Console.WriteLine("The answer of both {0} and {1} is {2}", num1, num2, addi);
```

And your class should look like this:

```
static class Addition
{
    static public int Add(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```